# Does bilinear models on vectors mean dot or outer product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have 2 vectors $x$ and $y$ where $x \in \mathcal{R}^{m}$ and $y \in \mathcal{R}^{n}$.
Does bilinear model mean?
$f(x,y) = x^TWy$ where $W \in \mathcal{R}^{m*n}$
**which result in a scalar**
or
$f(x,y) = W(x⊗y^T)$   where ⊗ is the outer 
product and $W \in \mathcal{R}^{m*n}$.
**which result in a matrix**

I checked 2 papers, the first one [Low-rank Bilinear Pooling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04325)
**in page 2 in equation 1** their bilinear model produce a scalar
while in [Compact Bilinear Pooling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.01847) **in section 3.1** they said "Bilinear models take the outer product of two vectors"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bilinear" is simply an adjective that you can apply to any function of two vectors to indicate that it is linear in each argument. So the linear map

$(x,y) \rightarrow x^TWy$

and the tensor product

$(x,y) \rightarrow xy^T$

can both be described as bilinear, even though their codomains are different.

Comment: What about the element-wise product between 2 vectors? The reason I mention it is because it's different than the dot and outer product because it's doesn't take into account all the interactions between the 2 vectors (like what the dot product does).